# How To Load Page fast In Razzel in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering, razzle

i am new to Razzle React App , i have created an application , but when i enter the url in the browser it first take time to load css , then after 3 - 4 s it load whole page , is there any way via which we can load page fast ,